# VUE variable.length works in template, but gives console warning

Tags: warnings, vue.js, string-length

I have a template in which I need to know the length of a provided variable...

```
{{ prefix }} {{ prefix.length }}
```

It spits out the correct information and seems to work just fine, but it gives this warning:

> [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "{ input_prefix:
>   (prefix.length > 0)}": TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   undefined (found in component: )

I would really like to do it right, and get rid of the warning. Any ideas?

Best regards
John Lajer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If prefix is null or undefined, by definition, it cannot have a length.

As a result, render the length via a ternary operator, using the length property if prefix exists and defaulting to zero if it does not exist:

```
{{ prefix && prefix.length ? prefix.length : 0 }}
```

Comment: I needed to `prefix.length.toString()` the value.

Answer (score 3):

You'll face problems when the value is null/undefined as pointed out by David.

I'd use a computed variable to solve this problem.

Ex.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    prefix: 'Some value'
  },
  computed: {
    prefixLength: function(){
      if(this.prefix){
        return prefix.length
      }
      return '';
    }
  }
})
```

Then you just use this in your template:

```
{{ prefix }} {{ prefixLength }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    prefix: 'Some value'
  },
  computed: {
    prefixLength: function(){
      if(this.prefix){
        return this.prefix.length
      }
      return '';
    }
  }
})
```

Then you just use this in your template:

```
{{ prefix }} {{ prefixLength }}
```